# Compare the speed of '.eq.' command between integer real and logical in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Intuitively, I think to compare two value the speed should be logical>integer>real, So I made this test program:

```
program t
logical :: a=.true.
real :: b=1.021341
integer :: c=1

real(kind=16) :: start, finish,test

call cpu_time(start)
test=0.0
do while (test<1000000.)
 if (a.eqv.a) then
  test=test+0.01
 endif
enddo
call cpu_time(finish)
print '("Time for compare logical= ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

call cpu_time(start)
test=0.0
do while (test<1000000.)
 if (b.eq.b) then
  test=test+0.01
 endif
enddo
call cpu_time(finish)
print '("Time for compare real= ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

call cpu_time(start)
test=0.0
do while (test<1000000.)
 if (c.eq.c) then
  test=test+0.01
 endif
enddo
call cpu_time(finish)
print '("Time for compare integer= ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start
end program
```

but the output is

```
Time for compare logical=  2.228 seconds.
Time for compare real=  2.200 seconds.
Time for compare integer=  2.200 seconds.
```

It seems they are no significant differences. Why I think the logical should be fastest. I use gfortran 5.4.0. My OS is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler isn't optimizing away the conditional test (although that could be naughty of it, options may allow it)?  Why would you expect any to be faster than another, when all values consist of the same number of bits?  [That is, do you think `.eqv.` need compare/load only one bit/byte, say?]

Comment: Making A, B, and C all DIMENSION(100000) and doing DO I = 1, 100000 may be enlightening.

Comment: Is REAL(kind=16) needed ?

Comment: You should include a loop with the sum and no logical test at all